# No XAML code-completion with RESHARPER?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms, resharper

we develop APP with C# and XAML, using Xamarin Forms.

We use VISUAL STUDIO 2017 and RESHARPER 2017.3

**We don't get auto-completition for element's attached properties** :-(

With VISUAL STUDIO'S default intellisense we do get it, but with Resharper's one, nothing: **no suggestions / auto completion** like you can see here:

[image]
[image]

We're just trying to use some "attached properties" of XAML elements.

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
  <BoxView Color="Yellow"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Shouldn't Resharp recognize them? They're official XAML markup, aren't they?

Comment: You have active license of Resharper?

Comment: Hi Miguel. We're using the official 30 Days Free Trial. It's a wonderful tool and we were planning to buy the yearly subscription at the end of the trial. It works perfectly with C# code... but we're stuck with this huge problem with XAML. And this is scaring us, because in 90% of the cases we'll need it to work this way...

Comment: that's likely should be reported here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-468811

Answer (score 0):

That because you're in the Label's tag. Creating an AbsoluteLayout IN a Label is a problem.

Here is my auto completion with Resharper and it works really good !

[image]

Comment: Hi JulienRcs, thank you for your answer. Anyway, we're NOT creating an AbsoluteLayout nested inside a Label. We're just trying to use the official XAML "attached properties" of an element, like this: AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,0.25,0.25". If you look at our screenshots, you see... there isn't the opening "<" in front of the  "Abso...." keyword. So, we wonder.... why Resharp doesn't recognize them ? They're part of the official XAML markup. How do you use them with Resharp ?